# dictionary ContainsKey method

Tags: c#, dictionary, contains

Please explain why dictionary's 'getAt' method fails

```
List<BString> infoKeys = new List<BString>(infoDict.Keys); 
if (infoKeys.Contains(TorrentFileKeyWords.FILES_KEY) == true) //"files"
{   
        List<BaseType> multiFiles = ((BList)dict[TorrentFileKeyWords.FILES_KEY]).Value; <<< this fails
```

So infoDict is a `Dictionary<String, BString>`
Contains on infoDict.Keys is used to find a specific item (of type BString)
But line 4 fails... doesnt have sens

I am not used with c#.. so what methods do I have to override (now i have: GetHashCode, ==, != & equals)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You haven't presented enough code to help you properly, and you haven't presented the error either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: What are the types really? If `infoDict` was a `Dictionary<String, BString>`, then `infoDict.Keys` would be a collection of `String`, not a collection of `BString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using `infoDict` in one place, and `dict` in another...

It's not clear why you're creating a list from the keys of `infoDict` rather than just calling `ContainsKey`, or (better) using `TryGetValue` to start with. Additionally, I would advise *against* a "B" prefix for your type names.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn’t need to copy your `Keys` to a new list to perform the lookup. In fact, you can check whether the key is present in the dictionary *and* retrieve its associated value in a single operation using the `TryGetValue` method:

```
BList bList;
if (dict.TryGetValue(TorrentFileKeyWords.FILES_KEY, out bList))
{
    List<BaseType> multiFiles = bList.Value;
    // use multiFiles here
}
```